# How to raise error when validation on nested attributes fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Here are 2 models: customer and address. A customer `has_one` address.

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address
  accepted_nested_attributes_for :address, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  validates :add_line, :presence => true
end

<% simple_form_for @customer do |f| %>
  .....
  <%=f.simple_fields_for :address do |builder| %>
     <%=render ('address', f: builder) %>
  <% end %>
<%end %>
```

address view

```
<%=f.input :add_line %>
```

`address` is nested attribute in `customer`. The problem we are having is that if `address` is modified wrongly (ex, a nil `add_line`) within `customer` view, there is no error (`@customer.update_attributes` in customer controller) popping up. Is there a way setting up the nested attributes in such a way `nil add_line` will fail the update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things caught my eye with your original post:

One,remember that you need a `belongs_to :customer` in the `Address` model.

Two, you need to add a validation in the Customer model

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address
  accepted_nested_attributes_for :address, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :address_invalid
  private
  def address_invalid(attributes)
    # add custom validation code here ... 
  end
end
```

Comment: There is belongs_to in model already. Is `reject_if` redundant to the validation in model `address`?  The `address_invalid` would repeat the validation in `address` model.

Comment: The problem we are having is that if the `add_line` is nil in `address` model, then the controller should raise the error instead of silently letting it passing. Try `!` and it does not raise error if there is validation failure in nested model.

Comment: Does it fail/error silently with the validation method in the `Customer` model?

Comment: Not with failure in `customer` model as I know.